# Issues with libboost_thread linking

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm just making my way through finishing the boost http server project, which was written in visual studio using msvc compiler. All went well until I started porting this to linux. Here's a linking error displayed in console

```sh
http_server.cpp:(.text+0x995): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/usr/bin/ld: http_server.cpp:(.text+0xa05): undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_setclock'
/usr/bin/ld: http_server.cpp:(.text+0xb83): undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
/usr/bin/ld: http_server.cpp:(.text+0xc69): undefined reference to `boost::thread::native_handle()'
/usr/bin/ld: http_server.cpp:(.text+0xc82): undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccFIQ0RA.o: in function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned long, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned long, boost::asio::io_context>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_context*> > > >::~thread_data()':
```

Here's my Makefile

```
STANDARD = c++11
LIBPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   
LINUX_THREAD=-lpthread
BOOST_THREAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.a

OUTPUT=cppserver
build_gcc:
    g++ -O2 -std=$(STANDARD) $(LINUX_THREAD) -o $(OUTPUT) CppServer/servers/http_server/http_server.cpp ;\
    CppServer/servers/http_server/connection.cpp CppServer/core/app.cpp CppServer/core/dbconn.cpp ;\
  CppServer/servers/http_server/response.cpp CppServer/servers/http_server/request.cpp ;\
    CppServer/math_unit.cpp  CppServer/main.cpp  $(BOOST_THREAD) -L$(LIBPATH)
```

I also tried to set BOOST_THREAD to 'boost_thread', but it failed as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `-pthread`, not `-lpthread`. How do you know that linking to the library is the only thing necessary to get pthreads support?

Comment: Linking is sensitive to order. I'd put `-pthread` last here (not `-lpthread`). Also, put `-L$(LIBPATH)` before `$(BOOST_THREAD)` (and make `BOOST_THREAD=-lboost_thread`) - And, the semicolons (`;`) on your compilation line looks wrong. Remove those.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it successfully compiles, albeit with some warnings, but it's not that important. During my struggles i had a strong suspicion that linking order matters, and now i clearly see that it does.

Comment: But why -pthread should be placed after -lboost_thread?

Comment: @ThreadedStream You're welcome! When having linking problems, the first thing to try is to place the library with the least amount of dependencies to the other libraries last. `pthread` does not need any of the other libraries you listed to function. `boost_thread` on the other hand likely needs functions inside `pthread`. When linking, the linker builds a dependency table. It sees that `pthread` needs `pthread_condattr_setclock` and keeps that in mind when parsing the rest of the libraries. If `pthread` had already been parsed, it wouldn't find it. It's also possible to resolve this by ...

Comment: ... specifying that it should parse a number of libraries multiple times. That can help if you have circular dependencies etc, but it also makes things slower, so it's better to try to list the libraries in an order where that is not needed.

Comment: I meant to say "_it sees that `boost_thread` needs `pthread_condattr_setclock` (which is inside `pthread`)_" - not what I wrote above :-)